# Suppress a specific ESLint warning: File ignored by default

Tags: eslint, grunt-eslint

Hopefully this is a reasonable question but it's possible I'm misunderstanding something. I get this warning raised on 9 seemingly random `.js` files in my project's `node_modules` dependency directory when I run ESLint from grunt. For example:

```
node_modules/cosmiconfig/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/type/js/function.js
  0:0  warning  File ignored by default. Use "--ignore-pattern '!node_modules/*'" to override
```

The [docs say](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories),

> /node_modules/* and /bower_components/* in the project root are ignored by default

That's all well and good, but I don't want these warnings raised every time I lint my actual code.

I have tried explicitly adding the `/node_modules/*` pattern to the `.eslintignore` in my project root, which hasn't helped. Using the command line flag suggested just makes ESLint raise errors on my dependencies, which isn't what I want either.

**Is there a way to tell ESLint that I explicitly don't want to lint my dependencies so that this warning won't be raised?** Having a default that raises warnings and cannot be turned off seems pretty silly.

Thanks for any help. Here are some of the relevant configs (full code is in the repo but of course `node_modules` is not checked in):
https://github.com/jshields/joshuashields.com/blob/master/.eslintrc.js
https://github.com/jshields/joshuashields.com/blob/master/.eslintignore
https://github.com/jshields/joshuashields.com/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was the files that I was targeting in my `Gruntfile.js`. My task was reaching down into the `node_modules` instead of my own code. I changed `'**/js/*.js'` to simply `'js/*.js'`:

```
diff --git a/Gruntfile.js b/Gruntfile.js
index 6b549f7..872abb2 100644
--- a/Gruntfile.js
+++ b/Gruntfile.js
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@ module.exports = function(grunt) {
                     //configFile:
                 },
                 files: {
-                    src: ['Gruntfile.js', 'stylelint.config.js', '**/js/*.js']
+                    src: ['Gruntfile.js', 'stylelint.config.js', 'js/*.js']
                 }
             }
         },
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try adding `**/node_modules/*` and `**/bower_components/*` to see if it solves the problem? (It might be that you have nested node_modules and bower_components).

Resulting .eslintignore:

```
/node_modules/*
**/node_modules/*
/bower_components/*
**/bower_components/*
```

Comment: Upvote because this was a smart suggestion, there were nested `node_modules`. However, I couldn't get this solution to work.