# eslint ignores dot directory descendant files "File ignored by default"

Tags: javascript, eslint

I recently started to get the

> 0:0 warning  File ignored by default.  Use a negated ignore pattern (like "--ignore-pattern '!<relative/path/to/filename>'") to override

message using `eslint` with ALE / VIM.

ALE cd to home directory and run the `eslint` command from there. For example if I edit:

```
~/tmp/.test/foo.js
```

It runs something like:

```
/bin/bash -c cd /home/user && \
/home/user/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js -f json --stdin \
--stdin-filename /home/user/tmp/.test/foo.js < /tmp/v7TXBK0/4/foo.js
```

I can replicate it by running:

```
~$ npx eslint tmp/.test/foo.js
# or
~$ node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js tmp/.test/foo.js
```

Even if I add a `.eslintrc.js` file in `~/tmp/.test/` with:

```
"ignorePatterns": [
    "!foo.js"
],
```

or other variants, it still gives the same warning and halts parsing. Using the `--debug` flag it show that the paths are added to ignore list. It also say:

```
  eslintrc:ignore-pattern   processed: { 
        basePath: '/home/user', 
        patterns: [ 
              '/**/node_modules/*', 
              '!/tmp/.test/**/foo.js' 
  ] }

  eslintrc:ignore-pattern Check {
        filePath: '/home/user/tmp/.test/foo.js',
        dot: false,
        relativePath: 'tmp/.test/foo.js',
        result: true
  }
```

What to do here to make it parse the files?

(If I run `eslint` from the target directory it works fine.)

My *real files* for current project are in a deeper tree; like: `~/.dir/sub1/sub2/*`

- [Eslint: warning File ignored by default. Use a negated ignore pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57947585/3342816)
- [Suppress a specific ESLint warning: File ignored by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50893015/3342816)

Answer (score 0):

Tried all kinds of patterns in local `.eslintrc.js` but to no avail.

Ended up using this as global `~/.eslintrc.js`, which works, but perhaps not the best solution:

```js
module.exports = {
        "ignorePatterns": [
                "!*"
        ]
}
```

This means one can not use `"root": true` in local / project rc file.